# Android View Pager set Page within Fragment

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I want to build a `ViewPager` with 2 Pages. On the first page you can choose a category. When a `List item is selected` the screen swipes to the second page and you can choose some subcategories.

I implemented the `clicklistener` and so on. But I have no idea how to set the current page from within a `fragment`. Is it even possible? Or do you have another solution for me? Hope you understand what I want to achieve.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, found a solution for my own. Thanks to Sayem for the hint.

I passed the ID of the ViewPager via bundle to my first fragment. in my fragment i could use then this simple code:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    viewPagerId = getArguments().getInt("viewPagerId");
    View rootView = (View) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_cat, container, false);
    populateListView(rootView);

    viewPager = (ViewPager) getActivity().findViewById(viewPagerId);

    return rootView;
}
```

and to switch pages then simply this:

```
viewPager.setCurrentItem(position);
```

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 2):

use `((ActivityName)getActivity()).getViewPager().setCurrentItem(position);`

note: `getViewPager()` should return the `viewpager instance`

Comment: What do you mean with (ActivityName)? Made a public method in my activity getViewPager(), but cant get a reference in my fragment with getActivity().getViewPager().setCurrentItem(position);

Comment: ActivityName should be the activity on which the ViewPager object resides

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
mPager.setCurrentItem(position);
```

Comment: But this only works outside the fragment, in the activity. I need a solution within the fragment. Or did i miss something here?

Comment: try by passing a reference of viewpager in first fragment. then in that reference you can set current item.